# CSS circle overlapping section

Tags: css

I would like my H2 title to appear like this image is showing [image]

At this moment this is how my code looks like

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.green-bg { background: #488429; }

.title-border { border-radius: .25rem!important; }


.text-title-center { text-align: center!important; color: #fff; font-size: 41px; }


.text-title-text-h2 { color: #fff; padding-top: 4rem; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl">YO!</button>

<section class="green-bg title-border">
<h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">H2 title in section</h2>
</section>
```

I am quite confused on how to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `position:relative` for the green background div and for the button i have set it to `position:absolute` aligned it horizontally using `left:50%` and `transform:translateX(-50%)` and move it vertically i have given half of the `height` of the `button` as `top:-35px` which will align it vertically half

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  top:-35px;
}

.green-bg {
  background: #488429;
  margin:100px 0 0 0;
  position:relative;
}

.title-border {
  border-radius: .25rem!important;
}

.text-title-center {
  text-align: center!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 41px;
}

.text-title-text-h2 {
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 4rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="green-bg title-border">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl">YO!</button>
  <h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">H2 title in section</h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display the button as a block element, adjust margins as needed.

```
margin: 0 auto -35px auto;
display: block;
position: relative;
```

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 1.33;
      border-radius: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto -35px auto;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    }

    .green-bg { background: #488429; }

    .title-border { border-radius: .25rem!important; }


    .text-title-center { text-align: center!important; color: #fff; font-size: 41px; }


    .text-title-text-h2 { color: #fff; padding-top: 4rem; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl">YO!</button>

    <section class="green-bg title-border">
    <h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">H2 title in section</h2>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl {
  position:relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 270px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1.33;
  border-radius: 35px;
}

.green-bg { background: #488429; }

.title-border { border-radius: .25rem!important; }


.text-title-center { text-align: center!important; color: #fff; font-size: 41px; }


.text-title-text-h2 { color: #fff; padding-top: 4rem; padding-bottom: 3rem; font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl">YO!</button>

<section class="green-bg title-border">
<h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">H2 title in section</h2>
</section>
```

I've added

```
  position:relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: 270px;
```

EDIT: this will put it at a fixed position, to get it at the center of the page you can add this:

```
  position:relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: calc(100% - 50% - 35px);  //35px = half the width of the circle.
```

Comment: well, was commenting about the scalability as you were using magic numbers, but I see you edited to fix that :) It also adds an unnecessary 30px "margin" on top though

Comment: oh yeah.. but you can fix that by setting it to absolute instead of relative, lol